# COUNT and COUNT, GROUP BY first count

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to pull a count of customers by order counts. I am able to pull both a count of orders and a count of customers with order counts but I cannot get the customer counts to sum up when the order counts are the same.

```
SELECT COUNT(orderid) AS ordrs, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(orderid)=COUNT(orderid) THEN COUNT(DISTINCT(custid)) ELSE "NA" END AS customr_cnt 
FROM orders;
```

I have also tried running

```
SELECT COUNT(orderid) AS ordrs, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(orderid)=COUNT(orderid) THEN COUNT(custid) ELSE "NA" END AS customr_cnt 
FROM orders;
```

Which just returns a count of both total orders and total customers

Comment: INSERT INTO orders(units, country, totalprice, delivery_cost, totaldiscounts, custid) VALUES(3,"CA",20.11, 0, 4.88, 3), (7,"NY", 90.00, 0, 10.00, 4),(3,"CA",50, 0, 10.00, 3), (7,"NY", 90.00, 0, 10.00, 5),(7,"NY", 90.00, 0, 10.00, 5) ;

Comment: Desired result would be a counting number of customers that have the same number of orders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to pull a count of customers by order counts.

Do you want two levels of aggregation?

```
select num_orders, count(*)
from (select custid, count(*) as num_orders
      from orders
      group by custid
     ) o
group by num_orders
order by num_orders;
```

Comment: Here is another example of a query i tried to run but gave me an error msg: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(custid)) AS cust_cnt, CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT(orderid))=COUNT(DISTINCT(orderid)) THEN COUNT(DISTINCT(orderid)
) ELSE "NA" END AS ordr_cnt FROM orders GROUP BY COUNT(DISTINCT(custid));

Comment: @ChristopherVolpacchio . . . Based on your comment, this would seem to be what you want.

Comment: Yes thank you so much! How would you describe what that is? A table alias??

Comment: @ChristopherVolpacchio . . . What what is?

Comment: The "o" that you put after the sub-query that allowed you to select the new field in the outer-query??

Comment: @ChristopherVolpacchio . .  That is a table alias.